# PDO JSON encode multiple HTML table rows

Tags: php, json, pdo

I am building a PHP function that is supposed to answer a jQuery Ajax call, depending on what id is submitted. There can be multiple forms with the same ID and I can't figure out why it is not sending back more than one record. PS: My dad will kill me if I don't figure this out by Monday...

My PHP:

```
<?php
  if (!empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    try {
      $objDb = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blankett', 'root', 'root');
      $objDb->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
      $sql = "SELECT * 
              FROM `forms`
              WHERE `id` = '$id'";
      $statement = $objDb->prepare($sql);
      $list = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      if (!empty($list)) {
        $out = array();
        foreach ($list as $row ) {
          $out[] = '<tr><td><a href="'.$row['link_form'].'">'.$row['name_form'].'</a></td> <td>'.$row['date_added'].'</td></tr>';
        }
        echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'list' => $out));
      } else {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
      }
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
      echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
    }
  } else {
    echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
  }
?>
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors or is the data at least being returned back to your AJAX call?

Comment: No, but when I enter the file URL in the browser I get {"error":true}

Comment: Well, that's expected since there is no data and `empty` will return true. So when you run this query outside of the AJAX script, does it return more than one record?

Comment: Then the problem has nothing to do with your AJAX script, but instead your query. Are you 100% sure that there is more than one record in the `forms` table that has the same ID? How many records *are* returned then?

Comment: I am sure that there are more than one record, but there are no records returned.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26794/discussion-between-evan-and-stenw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the prepared statement incorrectly. First, you should not be putting your variable in the statement. Second, you need to *execute* the statement.

Here is an example from the php.net site:

```
$sql = 'SELECT name, colour, calories
FROM fruit
WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour';
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => 150, ':colour' => 'red'));
$red = $sth->fetchAll();
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => 175, ':colour' => 'yellow'));
$yellow = $sth->fetchAll();
```

And here is how you would do it:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
FROM `forms`
WHERE `id` = :formID";

$statement = $objDb->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$statement ->execute(array(':formID' => $id));
$list= $statement ->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Thx man! Much appreciated I did not see the chat until two hours late.

Comment: heh, no problem. Glad I could help

Comment: DO you know what this does: echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'list' => implode('', $out)));